# restrict user to use one existing directory owned by oracle in aix

Tags: linux, oracle, aix

I did so many researches about this subject, I found nothing,

I have created a user and i assigned to him a home directory owned by oracle
I’m afraid if I change the permission of this directory no one can use it in other hand the user can use (CD) to jump into other directories

Comment: **Please** provide **more context**. 1. What research did you do // 2. **What product** are you talking about - I assume the database - what version of Oracle Db are you running then?

Comment: What does this have to do with Oracle? Normally user accounts own their own home directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign default shell to rksh or other restricted shell for the user.
so if they try to access other than their folder they can't.
Example:

```
 % rksh
$ cd /
rksh: cd: 0403-019 The operation is not allowed in a restricted shell.
$
```